# After calling Javascript function it appears the HTML and CSS break

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a bit of javascript that randomly selects an item from an array and prints it to the screen. The javascript should be triggered when the user hits a button and the item is printed to the screen. I've been able to get the function to work by having it trigger when the page loads as well as when the button is hit, the entire page reloads and a new item is printed to the screen.

But the goal is that the javascript is triggered when the user clicks the button and an item is printed to the screen. The user can then click the button repeatedly, each time a new item is printed to the screen

What is happening right now is when the button is pressed the javascript is triggered but the html and css for the page appear to break. The item prints to a blank page and the button to trigger the javascript disappears (so does any styling of the page) so the user can't click it again and have a new item printed.

I'm not exactly sure what is going on, or how to fix it. Here is the javascript I am using that is not working.

```
<div id="saying">
<script>
    function someFunc() {
        var choices = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"];
        var pick_choice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
        var post_choice = pick_choice
        document.write(post_choice)
    }
</script>
</div>

<input type="button" name="button" value="button" id="button" onclick="someFunc()";>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work. If you add it on to innerHTML of the saying element.

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" name="button" value="button" id="button" onclick="someFunc()";>
<div id="saying"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var saying = document.getElementById( 'saying' );

function someFunc() {
  var choices = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"];
  var pick_choice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
  var post_choice = pick_choice;
  saying.innerHTML += post_choice + '<br>';
}
```

Demo Here: http://jsfiddle.net/kdDY5/

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. I only want 1 item printed to the screen at a time but I figured out how to modify your suggested code to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `document.write` on a closed document reopens the document for writing, clearning the entire thing. Don’t use `document.write`. Instead, you can manipulate the DOM; here’s an example that adds `<div>` elements to the body:

```
function someFunc() {
    var choices = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"];
    var pickChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];

    // Create a new DOM element
    var itemContainer = document.createElement("div");

    // Create a new DOM text node
    var itemText = document.createTextNode(pickChoice);

    // Add the text node to the created element
    itemContainer.appendChild(itemText);

    // Add the created element to the body
    document.body.appendChild(itemContainer);
}
```

On modern browsers, you can also save the `appendChild(createTextNode())` step by assigning to the `textContent` property of the element.